# Recyclerview continue scrolling on position

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

I have a button that stops and starts the auto scrolling of the recyclerview. it does work fine, but when I'm manually scrolling and then clicking on the button to start the auto scrolling, it does start from the beginning. How can I make it so, that it continues scrolling at the position?

This is the function for starting auto scroll

```
public void startAutoScroll() {
    final RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, lstUserCard);
    final int speedScroll = 2400;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    if (timer == null && timerTask == null) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            int count = 0;
            boolean flag = true;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (count < myadapter.getItemCount()) {
                    if (count == myadapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                        flag = false;
                    } else if (count == 0) {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    if (flag) count++;
                    else count--;

                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(count);
                    handler.postDelayed(timerTask, speedScroll);
                }
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(timerTask, speedScroll);
    }
}
```

Would like to see some advice, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your index every time and restore it when you enable/disable auto scrolling each time.

To get your current top visible row index ;

```
int index = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); 
View v = linearLayoutManager.getChildAt(0); 
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - linearLayoutManager.getPaddingTop());
```

To restore recyclerview to this index;

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(top, 0);
```

Comment: You define "int index = ..." above but then index is never used.  Please advise.